# how to make a guess number game?

Tags: python

im trying to make a guessing game, user can input the level she wants, if 1 just numbers between 1,9 and if 2 between 10,99 otherwise between 100,99... here is my code:

```
fals = 0
while fals < 10:
    if level == 1:
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        y = random.randint(0,9)
    elif level == 2:
        x = random.randint(10,99)
        y = random.randint(10,99)
    else: # Next convert to else
        x = random.randint(100,999)
        y = random.randint(100,999)
    answer = x + y

    while (guess := input(f'{x} + {y} = ')) != answer:
        fals += 1
        if fals == 3:
            print(f'{x} + {y} = {answer}')
            break
```

problem is when i input 1 or 2 or 3 it always returns a 3digit question like 395 + 341
--- anyway the other problem is i want to ask 10 questions and also for each question if user inputs the answer 3 time false, program will give the user correct answer and keep asking other question

Comment: That's not a [mcve], but I would guess that `level` is a string and not an integer. `"1"` is not the same thing as `1`.

Comment: Note that the `input` function *always* returns a `str` data type - so this must be accounted.

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
fals = 1
while fals <= 10:
    level = int(input(str(fals)+". Enter level :"))
    if level == 1:
        x = random.randint(0,9)
        y = random.randint(0,9)
    elif level == 2:
        x = random.randint(10,99)
        y = random.randint(10,99)
    else: # Next convert to else
        x = random.randint(100,999)
        y = random.randint(100,999)
    answer = x + y

    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        guess = input(f'{x} + {y} = ')
        if int(guess) == answer:
            print("Correct")
            break
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            print("Answer ",answer)
   fals+=1
```

Hope this code works.